# Get current or future date from string with delimiters between some dates

Tags: mysql

I have text field (type = TEXT) with rows:

```
    :2013-04-12:2013-06-03:2013-07-03:2013-11-28:2014-02-28:2014-04-18:2014-04-25:
    :2013-11-15:2014-04-25:
    :2014-06-10:
    :2014-02-28:2014-04-18:2014-04-25:
    :2014-05-06:
```

How can I get only rows with current or future date? That is, only rows where meets current or future date.

Comment: Probably you should redesign your db

Comment: If this is even possible, it'll be much easier to do it not inside of SQL (and if there is moderate traffic on the system, do you want the DB doing all of that?)

Comment: @Uriil It's not mine architecture =(

Comment: your design does not even fulfill the first rule of normalization. the dbms is not prepared to work optimally with this kind of design. You need an extra table with one date per row "linked" to the original key (Primary key, foreign key link). If you really have to, look for string processing functions and temporary memory table.

Comment: @koriander It's not mine design, see my comment above =) I know all what you wrote, but... my problem described in this ticket.

Comment: the solution to your problem depends on what you can do. Ideally you should create another table to normalise the design. You don't have to change what you have, but you can add a table. Either to the file system or to memory. Then the query is trivial.